# Python regex: Iterate over a list of strings using re.findall

Tags: python, regex

I have a list which is nothing but a list of filenames.

```
['20190918_TrialBalance_TPBL.txt','20190918_ManagerBalance_TPCL.txt','20190918_ManagerBalance_TPCH.txt']
```

**Objective:**

I want to know whether the list contains any file whose name contains 'TrialBalance'.

**My Approach:**

I am trying to iterate over that list using `regex`.

```
import re
files=[]
for f in list_files:
    tbl = re.findall(r'trial.*\.txt$',f, re.IGNORECASE)
    files.append(tbl)
```

The above codes doesn't yield any result i.e. I am getting a blank list.

However, when I apply `re.findall` on individual items i.e. `re.findall(r'trial.*\.txt$',list_files[0], re.IGNORECASE)` I am getting proper answer.

Can anybody please help me in pointing out the missing line?

Comment: `any([True for i in list_files if 'TrialBalance' in i])`

Comment: Would your actual list contain \r` line endings by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re.findall` is **inefficient** for your case, use the following approach with prepared regex pattern and `re.search` feature:

```
import re

list_files = ['20190918_TrialBalance_TPBL.txt', '20190918_ManagerBalance_TPCL.txt', '20190918_ManagerBalance_TPCH.txt']
pat = re.compile(r'trial.*\.txt$', re.I)
trial_files = [f for f in list_files if pat.search(f)]

print(trial_files)  # ['20190918_TrialBalance_TPBL.txt']
```

---

Non-regex approach is also feasible:

```
list_files = ['20190918_TrialBalance_TPBL.txt', '20190918_ManagerBalance_TPCL.txt', '20190918_ManagerBalance_TPCH.txt']
trial_files = []
for f in list_files:
    f_ = f.lower()
    if 'trial' in f_ and f_.endswith('.txt'):
        trial_files.append(f)

print(trial_files)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler:

```py
files=[]
for f in list_files:
    if  'TrialBalance' in f:
        files.append(f)
```

Comment: I am aware of this approach. Just wanted to see if I can use `regex`

Comment: Okay... looks like you got your answer